# Get distinct user but all other rows associated

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I'm not sure how to explain.. I think GROUP might be what I'm looking for.. but I have never used it.

Data schema:

```
user1     col1   col2   col3   col4
user1     col1   col2   col3   col4
user1     col1   col2   col3   col4
user1     col1   col2   col3   col4
user2     col1   col2   col3   col4
user2     col1   col2   col3   col4
user2     col1   col2   col3   col4
user3     col1   col2   col3   col4
user3     col1   col2   col3   col4
user4     col1   col2   col3   col4
user4     col1   col2   col3   col4
user4     col1   col2   col3   col4
user4     col1   col2   col3   col4

etc..
```

What I am looking to do is query the database and get a list of DISTINCT users, but have all other cols with it.

```
example:

user1 col1   col2   col3   col4
      col1   col2   col3   col4
      col1   col2   col3   col4
      col1   col2   col3   col4

user2 col1   col2   col3   col4
      col1   col2   col3   col4
      col1   col2   col3   col4

user3 col1   col2   col3   col4
      col1   col2   col3   col4
```

etc..

I dont need the redundant user name.. I only need that once, but I need all other cols/rows associated with that same user.. until a new distinct user is up/next

I am looking to use GROUP?  I am not sure what to search for/use to get this result.

I am not very experience with MySQL ..so a nice easy to read/understand query or tut/link would be appreciated.

Apparently the Group_Concate has a size limit..  (which is no good for me here)

New question is how do I:

Only select/get DISTINCT name... but get a count of how many there are?

Example:

```
First1  Last1
First1  Last1

First2  Last2

First3  Last3
First3  Last3
First3  Last3
First3  Last3
```

Which would return:

```
First1 Last1 (2)
First2 Last2 (1)
First3 Last3 (4)
```

So I am only getting each unique name once.. but also getting a total of how many times (count?) its in there?

Update:  Using RADAR's last answer (in his comment)

I need to somehow integrate this into my current search query:  (I'm using PDO)

I need to somehow integrate this into my current query as it just uses %like% on an array of possible fields the user will use to search by:

```
// define the list of fields (easier to loop through and check for values)
$searchFields = array('first', 'last', 'suffix', 'trialdate', 'wcity', 'wstate', 'plaintiff');    
$searchConditions = array();

//loop through the defined fields & build query
foreach($searchFields as $searchField){
    // if the field is set and not empty
    if(isset($_POST[$searchField]) && $_POST[$searchField] != '') {

        $searchConditions[] = "`$searchField` LIKE '%" . $_POST[$searchField] . "%'";
    }
}

//build the query
$getExperts_sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";


// if there are conditions defined
if(count($searchConditions) > 0) {
    // append the conditions
    $getExperts_sql .= " WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $searchConditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I opt'd to apply the filters cumulative
}
```

I need somehow get what RADAR posted.. but also be able to grab the row data/contents to populate the page with?

I guess this will do it:

```
select *, count(*) from lnExpertWitness group by first,last;
```

Comment: Do you have to accomplish this within the database? I'd guess it would be a lot easier if you could accomplish this by running over the result set from your programming language.

Comment: I 100% agree with @MarcoAurélioDeleu.

Comment: I've used `GROUP_CONCAT` in situations like this: http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better to be done at the application layer

you can do the same with variables in mysql

```
select
  @num := if(@user_name = user, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
  @user_name := user as dummy,
  (case when @num = 1 then user else '' end) as user, col1, col2, col3, col4

from Table1, (select  @num := 0, @user_name:= '' ) t
```

To get the count, use `GROUP BY`

```
select col1, col2 , count(*)  as TotalCount
from table1 
group by col1,col2
```

Comment: To update:

This worked (sorta)

    SELECT CONCAT(first, ' ', middle, ' ',last) as fullName,     GROUP_CONCAT(casename order by casename SEPARATOR '<br>') FROM  lnExpertWitness GROUP BY CONCAT(first, ' ', middle, ' ',last)

But it has a size limit apparently.  :(


My new question (woudl I believe is easier) is how can I only display the DISTINCT (first & last names) but also get a count of the total?

ie:

First 1    Last 1
First 1    Last 1
First 1    Last 1

First 2    Last 2

First 3    Last 3
First 3    Last 3

Which would give me:

First1 Last 1 (3)
First 2 Last 2 (1)
First 3 Last 3 (2)

Comment: @whispers, select col1, col2 , count(*) from table1 group by col1,col2. also accept the answer.

Comment: Answer accepted..  this one ^ is much easier to understand!

update inital post with last portion of question (which was part of initial post.. so I understand the question changed

Comment: @whispers, you need to click  on the accept option on the answer

Comment: sorry, I have done so now. (I accidentally clicked the up-vote instead of accept)

Comment: How do I display the COUNT(*) number on the page?

I'm using a foreach loop to go through the returned records..

Displaying record data as such

    `$expert['first']`

How will this work for the count?

update: making an alias for it worked.

Comment: @ekad

Really?  Are you that desperate that you need to make these minor edits to my posts that are 3+ years old?  (really)..    that power  hungry/bored?

It comes across as very petty and annoying.